# Já quebrei a cabeça o dia todo [API] [FETCH] [POST]

Tags: javascript, api, post, cors, fetch

Eu criei uma api com express e fiz deploy, quando eu consumo ela tanto com GET quanto POST pelo postman, tudo ocorre normal.
Mas quando eu tento usar na minha pagina html o GET até funciona, mas requisições POST nem pensar.
Na API a regra é, quando um novo produto é criado, ela retorna um response com o produto e a mensagem de sucesso.
Exemplo:
`{products: [{"cod": 1, "description": "teste", "size": "30mm"}], message: "created!"}`

mas quando eu tento criar ele retorna:
body fica assim:
`{products: [{"cod": sequencia_aleatoria, "description": null, "size": null}], message: "created!"}`
Além de me retornar esse body também esta sendo salvo da mesma forma no banco de dados

E o response fica assim:
`Response {type: 'cors', url: 'https://minha-url/produtos', redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}`

com o body ReadableStream

Codigo da aplicação que esta consumindo

```
async function addProduct(id, des, size){
    const body = {
        cod: id,
        description: des,
        size: size
    }   

    const response = await fetch('https://minha-url/cadastrar', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({body}),
        headers: {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
    })

    return response
}
```

Codigo da API (endpoint de cadastro)

```
app.use(cors({
    origin: 'http://127.0.0.1:5500',
    methods: ['GET','POST','PUT','DELETE'],
    allowedHeaders: ['X-Requested-With', 'Content-Type', 'Accept', 'Origin', 'Authorization'],
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200
}))

app.post('/cadastrar', (req, res) => {
    database.addProduct(req.query.cod, req.query.description, req.query.size).then(
        data => {
            if (data.error) {
                res.send(data.error)
            } else {
                res.send({products: data.data, message: 'created!'})
            }
        }
    )
})
```

Comment: No front end, por que isso `body: JSON.stringify({body}),` ? Não seria `body: JSON.stringify(body),` ? No back-end, se a requisição é feita usando o verbo POST não haverão parâmetros de consulta na URL então `req.query` será ou um objeto vazio `{}` ou dependendo das configurações um objeto default. Cofigure o middleware `express.json()` e extraia os dados enviados no corpo da requisição com [`req.body`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.body).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

O problema parece estar relacionado à forma como você está enviando os dados no corpo da requisição POST da sua página HTML para a API. No código da aplicação que está consumindo a API, você está criando um objeto body e, em seguida, envolvendo esse objeto em outro objeto quando faz o JSON.stringify. Além disso, na sua API, você está usando req.query para obter os dados, mas na requisição POST do seu código da aplicação, você está passando os dados no corpo da requisição.

Aqui estão algumas sugestões para corrigir isso:

Código da aplicação que consome a API:

```
async function addProduct(id, des, size){
    const body = {
        cod: id,
        description: des,
        size: size
    }   

    const response = await fetch('https://minha-url/cadastrar', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(body),  // Remova o envolvimento extra do objeto aqui
        headers: {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
    });

    return response.json(); // Adicione isso para obter o corpo da resposta como JSON
}
```

Código da API:

```
app.post('/cadastrar', (req, res) => {
    const { cod, description, size } = req.body; // Use req.body para obter os dados do corpo da requisição

    database.addProduct(cod, description, size).then(
        data => {
            if (data.error) {
                res.status(400).send(data.error); // Use status 400 para indicar um erro de requisição
            } else {
                res.status(201).send({products: data.data, message: 'created!'}); // Use status 201 para indicar criação bem-sucedida
            }
        }
    );
});
```